# what is wrong with my pygame while importing pygame on python shell?(just to open blank window)(windows 8)

Tags: pygame

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> importpygame

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    importpygame
NameError: name 'importpygame' is not defined
>>> import pygame
```

just typed it manually and it just gives me that, im a first timer and i wanted to test if pygame would open a blank window so i could fallow along with some python 2d tutorials. could the problem lie in my instalation? because after i do it shows me options between repairing, and removing, i chose repair, and i didnt see anyone else with a window asking that. or possibly somthing to do with .py? thank you for helping out, i really appreciate it!

im totally new , i typed that manually, i just wanted to test an open window to see if it was working right, i dont know much , although it gave me an option when installing pygame to either repair or remove pygame, i chose repair, and in tutorials no one else had that window pop up could this be an issue? also could it be something to do with .py? because the file is "installed" in my dwnlds but idk if it recognizes it as a module

Answer (score 0):

If you were given the option to remove or repair pygame when running the installer, that means that it was *already installed*.

Running `import pygame` will *not* cause a "blank window" to open, it simply loads all of the appropriate objects into your interpreter session. To display a window, you need to initialise pygame and set up the display, for example (adapted from [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/intro/intro.html)):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 320, 240
black = 0, 0, 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

ball = pygame.image.load("ball.bmp") # pick an image
ballrect = ball.get_rect()

screen.fill(black)
screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
pygame.display.flip()
```